# drawing a triangle form java

Tags: java, loops, geometry

i'm trying to draw this form with java :
 for n=4:

```
      *******
      *** ***
      **   **
      *     *
```

but all i can get is this:

for n=4:

```
     **** ****
     ***  ***
     **   **
     *    *
```

here is the code for this:

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        System.out.print("Entrer n:");
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        n=x.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {    
            System.out.print("*");

            for(int j=0; j<n-1-i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            for(int k=0; k<n/2; k++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for(int j=0; j<n-i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

can someone help me with this,Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the general specification? What is n exactly? what do you expect for n = 1, 2, 3, 5, or 6?

Comment: n is the number of the ligns in the triangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the specification correctly, this should do it:

```
    int n = 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < n-i ; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for(int j = 0 ; j < i*2-1 ; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j = i==0?1:0 ; j < n-i ; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

n=1:

```
*
```

n=4:

```
*******
*** ***
**   **
*     *
```

n=6:

```
***********
***** *****
****   ****
***     ***
**       **
*         *
```

Comment: Thanks,that's exactly what i was looking for,but can you explain what's you did in the last loop,Thanks again.

Comment: I assume you mean `int j = i==0?1:0` this part. This is a ternary statement. `i==0?1:0` means "if `i` is 0, then this expression is 1, otherwise it's 0". The point of this, is because on the first line, we have `2(n-i)-1` *'s, while the other lines have `2(n-i)` *'s. This is a way of skipping a star in the first line. You could have also put this on the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

your problem in the loop is in this part

```
for(int k=0; k<n/2; k++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

solution :

```
for (int k = 0; k < i*2; k++) {    // solved
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

you need the number of spaces equal to the index of your line, so your line index is in the "i" variable

in line 0 you need 0 spaces

in line 1 you need 2 space

in line 2 you need 4 space

and so on

Comment: Have you tried this? How many spaces do you need for line 2? It's not 2.

Comment: @Cruncher the code is correct now, it's multiplication instead of division :D